# Translate Month-Day combinations in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, date, translate, cakephp-2.3

I can translate an individual month or day just fine using my `.po` files:

```
echo __('December'); //becomes diciembre
echo __('Thursday'); //becomes jueves
//...etc
```

But, when I use a date formate like this:

```
 echo __(date("j F, Y"));  //becomes 20 December 2012
```

It doesn't translate - I assume because I have translations for each month and day in individual lines.

Normally I would just do something like this:

```
__(date('j')) . ' ' . __(date('F')) . ' ' . __(date('Y'));
```

But, in the CMS, the admin is allowed to change the date to any format they want.  So, it could be "j F, Y", or "Y-m-d", or... anything else.

I thought maybe I could make a helper or something, that broke apart a date into pieces, and returns each part in a `__()`, but - this seems overkill.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I am setting my locale in the AppController:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, $currentLanguage['locale']);
Configure::write('Config.language', $currentLanguage['code2']);
```

Comment: couldn't you parse the format string entered by the admins and add the `__()` function around each letters ?

Comment: what is the value of `$currentLanguage['locale']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out CakePHP has a [TimeHelper `i18nFormat` function](http://api.cakephp.org/class/time-helper#method-TimeHelperi18nFormat):

```
$time = time();
$timestring = $this->Time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$this->Time->i18nFormat($timestring, "%A %e %B %Y");
```

Create a file "LC_TIME" (no extension) and put it in your `/Locale/ara/` folder (or replace 'ara' with whatever 3-char language code you want)

Copy the contents of [CakePHP's time_test LC_TIME file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Test/test_app/Locale/time_test/LC_TIME) and put it into yours (then save of course).

Then change it's contents to whatever language you want (I believe that example is in Spanish).

That's it!

**Notes:**

More details about the LC_TIME file here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.files%2Fdoc%2Faixfiles%2FLC_TIME.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `CakeTime` class (and thus the `TimeHelper`) uses the 'cake' domain for day and month names translation. So put those translations in `cake.po` file instead of `default.po`

Comment: well, for the cake po file to be used, one would have to use `echo __d('cake', 'December');` etc then.